# automate adding keychain certificate mac bash

Tags: mac, python, administrator, keychain

I am following
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688841/add-python-to-os-x-firewall-options

I want to automate this for my team, but I am finding nothing for keychains made by command line:

```
$ man keychain
No manual entry for keychain
```

and `Keychain command not found`

Can this be automated on mac? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is the command you want:

```
% man security
```

That said, I'm not sure whether Apple deprecated it or not.  It's still functioning on my 10.12.3 install.